# Can an Illusion of a wall of glass grant cover?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cover, wall

If I were to create the illusion of a **transparent** wall (of glass for example) 1/4 thick in a box surrounding my character, does this wall grant me full cover?

This question is different from: [Can an illusion give a player partial cover](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/127454/can-an-illusion-give-a-player-partial-cover).  That question creates a visible effect and asks about partial cover.

The core of the question is whether or not a transparent or translucent wall in and of itself, grants cover to those behind it.   The above example is the best way I can think of to readily manufacture such a structure.

The reason I am bringing this up as the answer to this question may have impacts on another game mechanic, but is being asked in isolation for clarity.

Comment: Cover isn't a condition, btw.

Comment: There is a distinct difference between that question and mine (which I saw).  Their illusion created a visible effect.  Mine does not, and mine is an attempt at total cover.

Comment: Glass walls are assumed to be visible though. If you want to ask about an invisible wall, you should make that explicit.

Comment: Done with boldings.  Thank you.   The point here is that its a wall that you can see through for line of sight.   I'm isolating variables to see if a full argument can be made against another generally accepted ruling I believe to be incorrect.

Comment: @purple_Monkey Hey, I think you understand where I am going with this, do you have a better suggestion in wording or question to address line of site / transparent barrier question I'm trying to get at?

Comment: I'm not sure this question is very answerable, but not because it's a duplicate.  It seems like you're looking for a very fine distinction between one thing an another.  If you're trying to get at an exact reading of the rules it might help if you specify whether it's transparent or invisible that you're talking about, and what is creating the illusion.  Cover says, "Walls, trees, creatures, and other obstacles can provide cover"; it's not clear from your question if you're asking if something that isn't perceivable is an obstacle, or  if you're asking something else.

Comment: I'll pull the invisible part of the wall.   I'm trying to see if the perception or the existence of a transparent barrier grants cover in and of itself.  In this case a glass box would grant cover, but an intangible glass box?   It has to do with wall of force and I'm trying to walk through whether or not line of sight is important, or if any sort of barrier made of any substance (illusion in this case) grants cover.

Comment: Note that wall of force is completely tangible so I'm unclear on how this helps clear that up. You could go up to a WoF send literally feel it with your hands since it stops any physical thing from passing through.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can an illusion give a player partial cover?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/127454/can-an-illusion-give-a-player-partial-cover)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Illusions cannot grant cover because cover requires an obstacle

> Walls, trees, creatures, and other obstacles can provide cover during
> combat, making a target more difficult to harm.

An illusion is not capable of being an obstacle for anything, thus it cannot grant cover under any circumstance. Anything that "hits" the illusory wall will pass right through it without any interaction. Thus, illusions cannot be used as cover. *They can be used to provide concealment though.*

Note that ability to see a target is not a factor in determining whether something can provide cover or not, only being an obstacle. So the illusory barrier being translucent or transparent or invisible even has no bearing on the matter. Something can be perfectly visible and still be under full cover. For example, being behind an actual (non-illusory) glass window pane will provide full cover as will being inside a gelatinous cube.

Comment: It would be helpful to address the distinction you are making about concealment (from earlier editions I understand the distinction with cover, but since concealment isn't a mechanical term in 5e it might not be obvious what the contrast is).